# <script type=text/javascript> $(function() { $('#buttonVal').click(function() {Alert not triggering on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger alert on button click when ever a text is entered on an input field

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
 $('#buttonVal').click(function() {
<input id="messageID" type="text"/>
var newAlert = $("input#messageID"),
    newAlertOk = $newAlert.val();
    alert("this is new alert "+newAlertOk);
</script>
```

When I click the button nothing happens. Please where am I wrong?
I have editted to include click event

Comment: Do you have a `click` event handler attached to your button? can you add a bit more code or a fiddle?

Comment: Yes I have a click event attached!

Comment: Please see the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove `$` from `$newAlert.val();`

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var newAlert = $("input#messageID");
  var newAlertOk = newAlert.val();
  alert("this is new alert " + newAlertOk);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="messageID" type="text"/>
<button>Click</button>
```

**Note**: dont write html elements inside `script` tag

Comment: Can I reassign the newAlertOK value to another input field with ID messsageID2 automatically

Comment: yes just do that `$("input#messageID2").val(newAlertOk );`

Comment: Yeah! On doing this, when I click the submit it recognizes the messageID2 as null until I add a space bar or make a change

Comment: What could be causing this?

Comment: difficult to answer without your code please add new answer and see this pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grgWpd